# .NET Core 3.1: Sharing lookup data between multiple requests

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 app. I have some lookup tables that I want to read when the app starts and I want to cache the data, so that multiple request can share the same lookup data.

How can I do this?

How can I read the lookup tables at startup? Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: Register a singleton that knows this info, and pass it to the constructor of any class that requires to know?

Comment: Hi Caius, is singleton over multiple request

Comment: Yes, singleton is "one instance for the lifetime of the hosting env"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding explanation, requested by user3552264.

#### How to use `IMemoryCache`?

1. Add `IMemoryCache` singleton in `Startup.cs`: `services.AddMemoryCache()`
2. Let inject `IMemoryCache` in your controller and use it in your method:

```cs
public class YourController 
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache memCache;
    private readonly ILookupTableSrc lookupTableSrc;

    public YourController(IMemoryCache memCache, ILookupTableSource lookupTableSrc) 
    { 
        this.memCache = memCache;
        this.lookupTableSrc = lookupTableSrc;
    }

    [HttpGet("LookupTable")]
    public async ActionResult<LookupTable> GetLookupTable(int tableId)
    {
        var lookupTable = memCache.Get<LookupTable>(tableId);
        if(lookupTable == null) 
        {
            var tableFromSrc = lookupTableSrc.GetById(tableId);
            lookupTable = memCache.Set(tableId, tableFromSrc);
        }
        return lookupTable;
    }
}
```

`GetLookupTable(int tableId)` retrieves `lookupTable` from `memCache`. If `memCache` is empty, you fill it by new object and it will be cached for next requests.

If you want to fill `IMemoryCache` in `Startup.cs`, please do it in existing `Configure(...)` method. As you see I added `memCache` and `lookupTableSrc` as parameters:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IMemoryCache memCache, ILookupTableSrc lookupTableSrc)
{
    lookupTableSrc.GetAll().ForEach(lookupTbl => memCache.Set(lookupTbl.Id, lookupTbl);
}
```

Comment: Bartlomiej, tnx for your reply. I"ll try this out

Comment: One more question: how can i fill the memorycache at startup? I want to fill all the records at once

Comment: I have multiple lookup tables

Comment: Ok, I updated my post. I dunno, from where you get your lookup tables, but I gave you example, how to use `IMemoryCache` in `Startup.cs`

Comment: @user3552264 Specify it as a parameter to Startup.Configure, a method which is called by the runtime after ConfigureServices method (which is where the memcache singleton is registered)

Comment: Hi Bartlomiej, i'm stuck of how to implement the ILookupTableSrc lookupTableSrc. I have 3 lookup tables from EF. Table A consist of 6 fields, Table b Consists of 5 fields And Table C consists of 6 fields. Can you give a example of how to define ILookupTableSrc. Tnx in advanced

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a IMemoryCache. You don't have to do this necessarily at startup, you can also do this in the first request.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

If you want to pre-populate the cache you can do so in an [HostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in the background.

Comment: Hi keulej, do you have a example of doing this?